# V-Sync in MFC and GDI+

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, flicker, dwm, vsync

hi
I'm using MFC SDI application for my mid term project. but every time i draw scene (with GDI) and "invalidate()"  it flicking occur.

I use DWM for double buffering and removing flicking but it rarely occur. i think problem is in the vertical syncing.what can I do for enabling virtual syncing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try overriding `OnEraseBkgnd` and simply return `TRUE` and do nothing else.  This will prevent the background being "erased" each time you draw.  Returning `TRUE` says "I've erased it`, even if you've done no such thing.